# How to talk to Spring +blazeDS services from apache Royale uisng RemoteObject

Tags: apache-royale

I have question here Right now I am least worried about UI for now. 
My ultimate goal is to talk to Spring Services(BlazeDS destinations which are defined in remoting-config.xml) from Apache Royale remote object.

I have started my work like in this way. 
1) I have created  method in my existing spring service which is integrated with balzeDs as mentioned earlier. 
2) I have written one new project using apache royale it is just trying to talk to spring service. Then after I have deployed 2 WARS in same tomcat but I am unable to talk to my service from apache royale because it is giving an error.

MY MXML:

```
<fx:Declarations>


        <mx:RemoteObject id="loaderService"  endpoint="http://localhost:8081/STARS/messagebroker/amf"  

        destination="reportService" result="handleLoadResult(event)"  fault="handleFault(event)" showBusyCursor="true" />

        <mx:RemoteObject id="remoteObject" destination="helloWorldRemotingService" endpoint="http://localhost:8081/STARS/messagebroker/amf"  

         result="handleLoadResult(event)"  fault="handleFault(event)" showBusyCursor="true"/>



    </fx:Declarations>






   <mx:VBox width="400">
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:VBox>
                <mx:Label text="Name to send via AMF"/>
                <mx:TextInput id="name_txt"/>
            </mx:VBox>
            <mx:Button label="Send to Name" click="loaderService.welcome()"/>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="{loaderService.welcome.lastResult}" height="15"/>
    </mx:VBox>
```

MY ERRor:

```
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936) 
        at flex.messaging.MessageBroker.routeMessageToService(MessageBroker.java:1373) 
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndpoint.java:1005) 
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103) 
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:158) 
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:44) 
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFilter.java:67) 
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:166) 
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291) 
        at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.service(MessageBrokerServlet.java:353) 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:107) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) 
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
        at com.sp.cpem.filter.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:25) 
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) 
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) 
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) 
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) 
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) 
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) 
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) 
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 


[ 
  errorReply: Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.ErrorMessage) 
    clientId = 470F44C5-680A-3F0D-D58C-605A866C0B1F 
    correlationId =BlazeDS]Unhandled error when processing a message: java.lang.NullPointerException 
  incomingMessage: Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage) 
    operation = null 
    clientId = 470F44C5-680A-3F0D-D58C-605A866C0B1F 
    destination = null 
    messageId = 
    timestamp = 1557396783081 
    timeToLive = 0 
    body = 
    [ 
      {headers={DSMessagingVersion=1, DSId=nil}, timeToLive=0, clientId=null, destination=, messageId=4CC0F8ED-8234-AEA2-F9B4-5CD3FD2D0DF0, correlationId=, body={}, operat 
ion=5, timestamp=0} 
    ] 
    hdr(DSEndpoint) = my-amf 
    destination = null 
    messageId = 470F4616-520F-9E4E-0484-14188756FFA6 
    timestamp = 1557396783218 
    timeToLive = 0 
    body = null 
    code =  Server.Processing 
    message =  There was an unhandled failure on the server. java.lang.NullPointerException 
    details =  null 
    rootCause =  null 
    body =  null 
    extendedData =  null 


Service: 
public class HelloWorldRemotingService { 

        private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(HelloWorldRemotingService.class); 

        public HelloWorldRemotingService() { 
                super(); 
                logger.debug("#################################Helloworld###############################################################"); 
        } 

        public String processHello(final String nameToSayHelloTo) 
           { 
                logger.debug("** Found @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@records:"); 
              return "Hello, " + nameToSayHelloTo + "!"; 
           } 

} 


Remote-config.xml: 

<service id="remoting-service" 
    class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService">

    <adapters>
        <adapter-definition id="java-object" class="flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter" default="true"/>
    </adapters>

    <default-channels>
        <channel ref="my-amf"/>
    </default-channels>
        <destination id="alertHomeService">                                    
                <properties>                                        
                        <source>com.sp.cpem.service.AlertHomeService</source>
                </properties>
        </destination>
        <destination id="helloWorldRemotingService">                                    
                <properties>                                        
                        <source>com.sp.cpem.service.HelloWorldRemotingService</source>
                </properties>
        </destination>
```

Please provide me steps and If anyone has example please let know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

for what I see you are using MX emulation components in Royale (MXRoyale library).
Here's a [working example project](https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/tree/develop/examples/mxroyale/RemoteObjectAMFTest) that you can test with a the [example java project](https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/tree/develop/examples/amf/SampleAmfWebApp).

About your code RemoteObject declaration has an endpoint that ends in "`amf`", but for the code you showit seems to end in "`my-amf`".

Then you call a `welcome()` method in java, but seems your service does not have that method. You have `processHello`.

You have to carefully check the code to see that all the points are well taken.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have declared "amf" because**<channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
            <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        </channel-definition>**  I forgot to tell that we are using spring security in backend service Can you please tell how can I tell my spring security to allow me for message borker request.

Comment: Hi Ravikanth, we're using Spring Security too, but I'm afraid our config and yours will be very different. We use as well Spring MVC to setup friendly urls for release and debug Royale versions and then make them avilable with Spring Security. The config is mostly similar to what we have in Flex, so you can check it from what you have there and make something similar